# Timer em Javascript não inicia

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou com a seguinte situação, dias atrás criei um timer com algumas condições e tudo certo. Porém agora preciso chamar a função mais de uma vez, pois o timer será executado independente para cada item vindo do banco de dados.

Então estou passando o tempo e o número do item que no caso será junto ao id.

Coloquei um alert pra ver se estava recebendo os valores e está , porém o timer não inicia, não estou conseguindo enxergar o erro.

```js
var segundosRestantes;
var down; 
var totalSeconds = 0;

//countDown timer
function countDown(itemX){

var item = itemX;
  
// pega a área do tempo
var timeDisplay = document.getElementById('time'+item);

 // transforma os segundos em mm: ss
 var min = Math.floor(segundosRestantes / 60);
 var sec = Math.floor(segundosRestantes - (min * 60));

 //adiciona um 0 à esquerda (como um valor de sequência) se segundos inferiores a 10
 if (sec < 10) {
  sec = "0" + sec;
 }
 if (min < 10) {
  min = "0" + min;
 }

 // concatenar com dois pontos
 var message = min.toString() + ":" + sec.toString();

 //agora mude a exibição 
 timeDisplay.innerHTML = message;

 
if(segundosRestantes > 0){
  $("#time"+item).addClass("pulseGreen"); 
 }
 
if(segundosRestantes <= 120 && segundosRestantes > 0){
  $("#time"+item).addClass("pulseYellow"); 
 }
  
   if(segundosRestantes <= 10 && segundosRestantes > 0){
  $("#time"+item).addClass("pulsered"); 
 }

 // quando o temporizador chegar a zero
 if (segundosRestantes === 0){
  clearInterval(down);
 $("#time"+item).removeClass("pulseYellow"); 
$("#time"+item).removeClass("pulsered");  
$("#time"+item).removeClass("pulseGreen");  
    
 $("#time"+item).addClass("nopulse");    
    //stopCountdown();
 }

 //subtrair dos segundos restantes
 segundosRestantes--;

}


function startCountdown(minutos,item){
  
 totalSeconds = 0;
  clearInterval(down);
 var item = item;
  var minutes = minutos; //recebe minutos
  //alert('item='+item+' min '+minutes);
 
 // verifica se foi informado os minutos
 if (isNaN(minutes)||minutes == ""||minutes==null){
  document.getElementById('time'+item).innerHTML='--:--';
  return; // para a função caso verdadeira
 }

 segundosRestantes = minutes * 60;
 down = setInterval(countDown(item), 1000);
 
}
```

```css
#timeClock{
 position:relative;
 font-size:14px;
 margin:0 auto; 
}
#timeClock{
 float:left;
}

#minutes{
 width:80%;
 position:absolute;
 left:50%;
 top:50%;
 transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
 font-size:1.5em;
 padding:10px;
 margin-right:10px;
 text-align:center;
 max-width:400px;
}

.nopulse{
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px;
  border-radius: 2px;
 }

.pulseGreen{
  background: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px;
  border-radius: 2px;
 }

.pulseYellow{
 background: #ff9900;
  color: white;
  position:relative;
 padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  animation: pulse 0.5s linear infinite;
}

.pulsered{
 background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  animation: pulse 0.5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes pulsered{
  0%{font-size:100%;}
  50%{font-size:110%;}
  100%{font-size:100%;}
}

.pulseStop{
 background: red;
  color: white;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>

</head>

<!--Count Down-->
<span id="time1" class="nopulse timeClockInput">00:00</span>
<script> setTimeout('startCountdown(20,1)',1000);
</script> 
<br>
<br>
<!--Count Down-->
<span id="time2" class="nopulse timeClockInput">00:00</span>
<script> setTimeout('startCountdown(18,2)',1000);
</script> 
<br>
<br>
<!--Count Down-->
<span id="time3" class="nopulse timeClockInput">00:00</span>
<script> setTimeout('startCountdown(13,3)',1000);
</script>
```

Exemplo da minha primeira versão:
https://codepen.io/aquiles-maior/pen/qBBNaXw

Comment: Consegui refazer o código usando o jquery Countdown. Simplesmente incrível essa lib. Quem precisar, solução ta aqui ó:
https://codepen.io/aquiles-maior/pen/WNNoGMx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu código tem dois problema básicos:

- Está usando uma mesma variável para controlar 3 diferentes timeouts;
- Está fazendo a chamada ao `setInterval` parassando parâmetros de uma forma que não funciona.

Para o primeiro item, pode corrigir o problema declarando 3 variáveis:
`var down1, down2, down3;`

Na function, como recebe o item por parâmetro, precisa pegar a variável dinamicamente. Para isso, pode usar o `window["nome-da-variavel"]`, então pode montar dinamicamente o nome, assim:

```
var downName = 'down' + item;
clearInterval(window[downName]);
```

O segundo ponto, declare a passagem de parâmetros dentro de uma `function` que vai funcionar, assim:

`setInterval( function() { countDown(item); }, 1000 );`

Aqui seu código com as alterações:

```js
var segundosRestantes;
var down1, down2, down3;
var totalSeconds = 0;

//countDown timer
function countDown(itemX) {
    var item = itemX;

    // pega a área do tempo
    var timeDisplay = document.getElementById('time' + item);

    // transforma os segundos em mm: ss
    var min = Math.floor(segundosRestantes / 60);
    var sec = Math.floor(segundosRestantes - (min * 60));

    //adiciona um 0 à esquerda (como um valor de sequência) se segundos inferiores a 10
    if (sec < 10) {
        sec = "0" + sec;
    }
    if (min < 10) {
        min = "0" + min;
    }

    // concatenar com dois pontos
    var message = min.toString() + ":" + sec.toString();

    //agora mude a exibição 
    timeDisplay.innerHTML = message;


    if (segundosRestantes > 0) {
        $("#time" + item).addClass("pulseGreen");
    }

    if (segundosRestantes <= 120 && segundosRestantes > 0) {
        $("#time" + item).addClass("pulseYellow");
    }

    if (segundosRestantes <= 10 && segundosRestantes > 0) {
        $("#time" + item).addClass("pulsered");
    }

    // quando o temporizador chegar a zero
    if (segundosRestantes === 0) {
        clearInterval(down);
        $("#time" + item).removeClass("pulseYellow");
        $("#time" + item).removeClass("pulsered");
        $("#time" + item).removeClass("pulseGreen");

        $("#time" + item).addClass("nopulse");
        //stopCountdown();
    }

    //subtrair dos segundos restantes
    segundosRestantes--;

}


function startCountdown(minutos, item) {

    var downName = 'down' + item;
    totalSeconds = 0;
    clearInterval(window[downName]);
    var item = item;
    var minutes = minutos; //recebe minutos
    //alert('item='+item+' min '+minutes);

    // verifica se foi informado os minutos
    if (isNaN(minutes) || minutes == "" || minutes == null) {
        document.getElementById('time' + item).innerHTML = '--:--';
        return; // para a função caso verdadeira
    }

    segundosRestantes = minutes * 60;

    window[downName] = setInterval(function() {
        countDown(item);
    }, 1000);

}
```

```css
#timeClock{
 position:relative;
 font-size:14px;
 margin:0 auto; 
}
#timeClock{
 float:left;
}

#minutes{
 width:80%;
 position:absolute;
 left:50%;
 top:50%;
 transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
 font-size:1.5em;
 padding:10px;
 margin-right:10px;
 text-align:center;
 max-width:400px;
}

.nopulse{
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px;
  border-radius: 2px;
 }

.pulseGreen{
  background: green;
  color: white;
  padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px;
  border-radius: 2px;
 }

.pulseYellow{
 background: #ff9900;
  color: white;
  position:relative;
 padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  animation: pulse 0.5s linear infinite;
}

.pulsered{
 background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  animation: pulse 0.5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes pulsered{
  0%{font-size:100%;}
  50%{font-size:110%;}
  100%{font-size:100%;}
}

.pulseStop{
 background: red;
  color: white;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>

</head>

<!--Count Down-->
<span id="time1" class="nopulse timeClockInput">00:00</span>
<script> setTimeout('startCountdown(20,1)',1000);
</script> 
<br>
<br>
<!--Count Down-->
<span id="time2" class="nopulse timeClockInput">00:00</span>
<script> setTimeout('startCountdown(18,2)',1000);
</script> 
<br>
<br>
<!--Count Down-->
<span id="time3" class="nopulse timeClockInput">00:00</span>
<script> setTimeout('startCountdown(13,3)',1000);
</script>
```

Comment: Poxa cara que explicação top, obrigado irmão!!! 
testei a function countdown e agora ta recebendo certinho, e agora  o contador inicia, porém ele está misturando alguma informação pq ta meio maluquinho.

Comment: legal, não esqueça de marcar a resposta se ajudou no seu problema. qto a ficar maluco, o que quer dizer?